# Shop Wiring Bewilderment

Tags: electrical

I'm working on rewiring a basement/shop area. The problem I am having is figuring out how to wire it all together using the least amount of wire as possible. I have installed 2x 30 amp breakers already. I began wiring up the first of twelve double gang boxes and quickly realized i was in over my head. In the attached picture i need the 4 black circles to be powered by the black switch, and the same thing for the blue and green ones. I need the red circles to be always hot though. my power source is on the left and the 3 switches are located about 50 foot away from that. I was planning on using one of the 30 amp breakers to power the black, blue, and green outlets. And the other 30 amp breaker to power the remainder red circles. The black, blue and green outlets are for the overhead LED fluorescent lights. Thank you in advance for your help.[image]

Comment: What country are you located in? And what size wire are you using?

Comment: I am located in the U.S. and using 12/2 Romex

Comment: Your definitely in over your head.  With 12 gauge wire, the maximum breaker size is 20amp.

Comment: Say i use 20 amp breakers would you be willing to take a stab at it then?

Comment: What types of things do you plug in?  Not all shops are created equal.  For example my next door neighbors “shop” has a potters wheel (a 20amp dedicated circuit) and candle making equipment (each warmer needing its own circuit).

Comment: the black, blue, and green circles run a total of 12 efficient LED fluorescent lights. 4 lights per switch. The other ones which are always hot one things like, air compressor, 2x dog shocking collars, 1 little radio, 1 deep freezer, 1 motorcycle charger, 1 boat charger, a kobalt workstation, 4 handheld drill chargers, etc etc, etc. Nothing real serious at the moment. I do have a little wire welder but its still in the shed for now. Theres also other little things like table saws, drill presses, etc etc.

Comment: None of these that are on the red circles run constantly except the freezer and the 2 dog shocking receiver boxes.

Comment: At the moment, 2 vote-to-close and one downvote on the question... maybe those folks could step forward and explain their actions. I see this as a genuine question where someone can benefit from the experience of the community. So c'mon: tell the world how this question could be improved.

Comment: i have successfully wired up the 3 switches and begun to run the wiring to the corresponding colored sections. i really appreciate your help Aloysius. i was frustrated after half a day of trial and error as i tried to start at one end and work my way to the other end. the black and red end is the end that i was working on and what was messing me up is trying to wire the lights and the constant power side at the same time.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate doesn't call for improving the question, but rather, the *questioner*.  Has absolutely *zero knowledge or experience* and *already bought all the stuff*, and yet *is concerned about cost*.  These things are contradictions, if you care about cost, you don't buy first. His promise to downbreaker to the legal 20A rings hollow.  His goals/urgency seem to imply a rush to ding-dong this thing together fast, with no interest/ability to sink the time to gain competence.  Nobody wants to help him burn his house down.

Comment: @Harper What is wrong with you? I implied at no time that i was not eager to change the breaker to 20 amps. The last thing i want to do is burn down my house. My lack of this knowledge is why i came here hoping for some guidance. Yes i showed alot of rush in purchasing the items i have. But at no time was this a rushed project. Hell look at the drawing or do you need the other 3 drawings. Hell I'll even give you a 4th and 5th drawing of the front deck layout that im doing next. I'm a very careful planner but forgive me for not wanting to pay alot to someone else when i can learn how to do it.

Comment: I also own my own semi truck and hate paying a mechanic to fix it as well. Will you critcize me when i need automotive guidance?

Comment: @CrunchyBacon sorry for being such a grouch.  Some of the things you said just rang like things seen here before.   Round out your learning and , you'll be in good shape to work efficiently and safely. It's a nice place to be.  Honestly it breaks my heart to hear about things like the Oakland live/work warehouse fire, when doing it right is  so doable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't overcomplicate things.

Run power to the switches. Run switched power from the switches to the switched outlets. (Not sure why you aren't hardwiring the lights, but whatever makes sense to you...) Your wiring would be less complicated if the switched outlets were in the same junction box. Your wiring would also be less of a curse if you were using 4-gang boxes instead of 2g ones side by side.

If you had additional circuits available, I'd think about using them. Here's why: if you use your lighting circuit to power tools, you run the risk of popping a circuit breaker and leaving yourself stumbling around in the dark. Best case would be an individual circuit for lights, and then two more circuits for tools. (A dust collector and saw, for instance might not co-exist happily on one circuit.) If you had the two "tool" circuits, you could stagger the circuits between junction boxes. (Not mix them in the j-boxes -- that's legal but too much complication.)

Since there's a lot going on in your junction boxes, my personal opinion is that you should use Ideal brand In-sure nPort connectors (or equivalent). Again, my opinion, but I think they're more forgiving than wire nuts when you're shoving 12awg wire around and trying to make it all fit.

Having your electrical buddy visit before you start will save you acres of heartache, wasted time and wasted materials. Trust me.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I am starting at the switches with power first. The lights dont draw alot of power but i would prefer to be able to shut them all off at the same time or just turn on certain sections. i currently have them all running via extension cords and its a nightmare at night to turn them off. most nights i just say to hell with it. The only circuits that i have additionally are in the house above. I live next to a river and the house is 9 ft above the shop area im trying to fresh wire. The lights will all be on a separate breaker from the other outlets.

Answer (score 2):

1. Return everything you can.
2. Go to the library and look at their books which are primers on doing home electrical wiring.  Browse all of their such books, and grab the one that seems in scope and feels the most accessible to you.  Read it thoroughly, not "twittery ADD skimming".   You can skip stuff like subpanels, wells, stoves and hot tubs since you're not doing that.
3. Inventory what you still have.
4. Think about what you want to do, and come back here and ask "here's what I want, here's what I've got, what advice do you have for minimal waste of material and keeping new purchases sane?
5. Diagram out what you intend to do.
6. Decide whether you are going cables vs conduit.
7. Go to the town hall and **pull a permit**.   This will mean your plan gets some oversight from the local inspector, which will further help avert errors.  It will mean a final inspection/sign-off before completion.  It will also assure you don't get nailed on it when you sell your house and be forced to pay a pro to fix it out of your house proceeds.
8. From now on, go to a genuine electrical supply house, rap with the clerk about how you are sick of big-box bad advice, but were there for the discounted prices, and that you had heard the were actually fairly priced.   The reason to do this is a) save money, and b) stop being poisoned by the absolutely awful advice dispensed by the $9/hour big-box clerks.

---

Let's say we're at #4.

Your proposal, as stated, will place 2 different circuits inside the same electrical box.  That's not a big deal, but it absolutely requires you **understand keeping hots and neutrals separate**.  It will also save wire to do this other ways.

A separate circuit just for lights is very wise, but will be more expensive to wire.

Putting your entire shop on one circuit is more concerning.  Depends what you plan to do with your shop. I just have to think you'd be better off with more than one circuit for receptacles if you can swing it.  One area it helps you is shop *receptacles* generally must be GFCI - lighting does not.  (Though if the main panel is above the flood zone and the circuit is not , GFCI always helps.)

As a cost savings, I might make 1 circuit per section, putting the lighting on the receptacle circuit.  This avoids having 2 circuits in a box.  You run the risk of a breaker trip blacking out the lights, but you'll probably have at least 2 banks of lights on.

When a freezer loses power, that's bad news, because usually nothing warns you of this.   Your worst risk is of a freezer in the same GFCI zone of a circuit, tripping because something else in the zone tripped the GFCI.  Therefore I prefer dedicated circuits for freezers, and try to find a way to omit the GFCI.

Using receptacles for lights is perfectly reasonable - most of my installations are this - *but all mine are located on the ceiling*.  Luminaires are allowed to connect with flexible cords, but only within reason - I don't think the inspector would approve an arrangement which invites cords (or gasp, extension cords!) being stapled to the wall or draping across workbenches.

Where you see knee level switched receptacles for lamps, that is a cheap method used in newer housing stock, and is intended only for floor or table lamps, not ceiling-hung lights.

If you are not putting lights and receptacles in the same place, you can divide and conquer - install the lighting circuits in one project and the receptacles in the other.

Comment: Thank you Harper. This helps alot. I am returning the 30 amp breakers in a bout 30 mins. I will be grabbing 6x 20 amp instead. I have a total of 10 available slots in the fuse panel at the far end of the house. I'll run the lights on a separate breaker and then each column with 8 outlets will have its own  breaker. Thank you. i also underestimated the proper wire nuts needed as I'm having a REALLY hard time twisting 4x 12 awg together lol.

Comment: THIS FOLKS.  This right here is the advertising poster for "get a lot of extra spaces in your panel".   10 extra spaces and OP can do what he wants!  Freedom!

Comment: @CrunchyBacon yeah on the nuts I find it best to aim for the middle of their working range.  Reds for >2 #12.

Comment: Hey, I sorry I don't meed your definition of what is right.  I would rather be wrong and prevent a fire than be right by your standards!  When a child is hurt because of a fire I want you to explain to the parents that the 'right' answer didn't fit your criterion. l speak from more than 40-years in the trade.  I've seen the fires caused be bad wiring.  I tell people on a regular basis that what they are doing could cause a fire.  Anything less is just rearranging the chairs.